# Uninitialized Constant error using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Devise on my User model, and since running `rake routes` tells me I have a `users` path (it GETs /users, which is what I want), I was expecting that route to work in my app.

But, I'm getting an `uninitialized constant UsersController` error when going to `/users`. I have a User Controller, and even tried using a fake index method, but it's still not working.

I'd like to be able to have a page that shows the logged in user's information, along with some data from other models it has a relationship with.

Thanks! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually get this error when I have misnamed the controller or route.  Try making sure you are consistent in your route controller with whether you controller is "UserController" or "UsersController".  Also check how it is specified in the routes.

A good way to avoid this is to write a simple rspec unit test on the controller so you can catch this issue earlier.